# Que lenguaje, framework, usar para crea una WebApp que solo se ejecute en el navegador

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, blazor

no tengo experiencia en web, pero quiero aprender haciendo un pequeño desarrollo.
Necesito crear una aplicación web (con formularios, y conexión a un TCP/socket en localhost) que se pueda ejecutar desde el navegador y que solo se necesite abrir el index.html y esta cargue pero me gustaría usar una tecnología nueva pero no se cual, me gustaría leer sugerencias

Condiciones:
-No requiera ejecutarse en un servidor web (IIS,Tomcat, Apache, etc).
-Tenga librerías que den capacidad de conectarse a un TCP socket en localhost.
-Se puedan crear formularios.
-Si es posible algo diferente a JS Puro

Es posible una WebAssembly?

Como ven desconozco del web pero quisiera saber que me aconsejan aprender para hacer esta webapp

Gracias a todos

Comment: Te recomiendo te des una vuelta por [ask] y de paso hagas el [tour], pues tu pregunta tiene serios problemas de formato y va a terminar cerrada

Comment: Como ha mencionado @beraM, por favor, revisa la seccion de como preguntar.

Comment: Para empezar el desarrollo web no necesitas TCP/IP; puedes empezar simplemente leyendo del disco, usando `File -> Open File ..." (Firefox), o escribiendo la URL `file:///home/candid/dev/test.html`. El protocolo `file:` dice que el archivo se lee desde el disco (la sintaxis mostrada es para Linux; en Windows debe ser diferente).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver..
Vamos por partes dijo jack el destripador.

Primero te recomiendo leer un poco de como funciona un Navegador web.
Para poder abrir un archivo HTML y hacer un post, como vos mencionas, podes crear un archivo y abrir lo directamente en el explorador seleccionado: Archivo -> Abrir.
Pero esto tiene muchas limitaciones.

Para cualquier otro tipo de acceso al archivo te recomiendo tener un server el cual escucha en un puerto, entiende tu peticion y te devuelve tu "archivo.html".
Esto lo podes lograr con cualquier servidor IIS, Apache2, nodejs etc.

Los nuevos Frameworks de Javascript tiene su propio mecanismo para "montar" un servidor localmente (es lo mismo que tener apache, iss, etc), el cual te provee los archivos cuando ingresas la URL en el navegador web.
Cualquiera es buena opcion y tendras que decidir vos, basandote en los requerimientos de tu proyecto cual es la mejor opcion.

Los mas populares son AngularJS, React y VueJS.
Si estas aprendiendo, particularmente te recomiendo VueJS ya que la curva de aprendizaje es la mas facil de todas.

Podes largarte a aprender un framework pero parece que tenes que primero hacer un paso atras y leer en general como funciona internet y como se proveen y se acceden archivos, que funcion cumple un servidor etc, ya que parece estas mezclando conceptos.

Si es para empezar con HTML y CSS, creando el archivo y haciendole doble click te alcanza para tus pruebas.

Te recomiendo cerrar la pregunta.

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones no se deben responder pues terminan cerradas

Comment: @BetaM La pregunta ya la reporte yo :), se pueden y se deben responder si uno tiene ganas y no le interesan los puntos, ademas era un comentario muy largo, llevo bastante en SO gracias por el consejo igual

Comment: Tu respuesta es correcta y valioso, pero alienta malos hábitos, como preguntar en lugar de investigar.